# Telerik TopPane height auto?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css, telerik

Problem: I can't set the height to auto in Telerik TopPane. I end up with a default height value of 230px.

Code:

> ```
> <div id="ParentDivElement" style="height: 100%;">
>       <telerik:RadSplitter ID="MainSplitter" runat="server" Height="100%" Width="100%"
>             Orientation="Horizontal" Skin="Outlook" BorderSize="0">
>             <telerik:RadPane ID="TopPane" runat="server" Height="auto" MinHeight="0" MaxHeight="0"
>                 Scrolling="none" BorderStyle="None" EnableAjaxSkinRendering="False" 
>                 EnableTheming="False">
>                 <!-- Place the content of the pane here -->
>                 <div id="tcp_main">
>                     <div id="tcp_logo">
>                         <image src="images/test/logo.png" alt="logo" />
>                     </div>
>                     <div id="tcp_text">
>                         <h1> Hello world </h1>
>                     </div>
>                 </div>
>             </telerik:RadPane>
>             <telerik:RadSplitBar ID="RadsplitbarTop" runat="server" EnableResize="False" />
>             <telerik:RadPane ID="MainPane" runat="server" Scrolling="none" MinWidth="500">
>                 <telerik:RadSplitter ID="NestedSplitter" runat="server" Skin="Outlook" LiveResize="true">
>                     <telerik:RadPane ID="LeftPane" runat="server" Width="200" MinWidth="150" MaxWidth="400">
>                         <!-- Place the content of the pane here -->
>                     </telerik:RadPane>
>                     <telerik:RadSplitBar ID="VerticalSplitBar" runat="server" CollapseMode="Forward" />
>                     <telerik:RadPane ID="ContentPane" runat="server">
>                         <!-- Place the content of the pane here -->
>                     </telerik:RadPane>
>                 </telerik:RadSplitter>
>             </telerik:RadPane>
>         </telerik:RadSplitter>
> </div>
> ```

Condition: If I set the height property to auto I get the following error:

```
Property value is not valid.
```

and if I click on details I get:

```
'auto' cannot be parsed as a unit as there are no numeric values in it. Examples of valid unit strings are '1px' and '.5in'.
```

Question:
It looks like the auto isn't accepted for height in Telerik controls, what do I have to do to end up with auto or it's equivalent functionality?

Note: I don't want to use !important in css.

Answer (score 1):

Set the height attribute as a [RadPane](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/allmembers_t_telerik_web_ui_radpane.html) style property which is inherited from [WebControl.Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx47a5t2), the style attributes are rendered the same as individual properties which are added to the style collection OnPreRender.

```
<telerik:RadPane ID="TopPane" runat="server" 
            Scrolling="none" BorderStyle="None" EnableAjaxSkinRendering="False"  
            EnableTheming="False" Style="height: auto; min-height: 0px;">
```

Comment: This does not work. The height is set, and the height adapts when you change the window size with javascript. But the height is not set with css auto, and so functions differently. I would like to have the same functionality as "auto" has in css.

Comment: You cannot achieve the same effect where the SplitterPane is automatically moved unless you implement custom javascript to do so. What I suggested does work as if you set the overflow property to scroll you will see the div expand.

Comment: I don't care about moving the splitterpane automatically. I want to set the width to "width: auto;"

Answer (score 1):

I know that you mentioned not wanting to set anything as !important in CSS, but for the sake of experimenting have you tried the following?

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">  
    .AutoHeight  
    {  
        height: auto !important;  
    }  
</style>
```

Markup:

```
<telerik:RadPane ID="TopPane" runat="server" ... CssClass="AutoHeight" ...>
```

This should force the height to be auto. If this works, then you could go ahead and modify the Telerik Skin you are using (Outlook) with an updated height attribute. You shouldn't have to set !important if you update this in the skin.

As a side-note here though, the RadSplitter control relies on the RadPane's to have a specific size set (hence the min/max height/width etc.) and you might want to look into just having a regular `<div>` element as the "top panel" and then only use the RadSplitter on the bottom half.